# How to add time delay and fix position to Bootstrap 3.0 scrollspy?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a project with Bootstrap 3.0 and using scrollspy, the scrollspy working good but there is some notes:

1- how to add a time delay when the page scroll or when clicking on one of the links in the navbar to take me to the position i pointed to ?

2- scrollspy position is not correct ( e.g. when i scroll to specific position always i'm above it with about 60px difference ).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the time delay, when i understand you well, try something like:

```
var tmp = $.fn.scrollspy.Constructor.prototype.process;

$.fn.scrollspy.Constructor.prototype.process = function () {
  console.log('ff wachten')
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){tmp.call(that)},5000);

}
```

Add this after the inclusing of scrollspy.js. But ou also will have to add a delay on the click event it self like:
(from: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/delay-sleep-pause-wait/)

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(){sleep(5000); console.log('slept');  return true;});
```

Now you got a double delay, so make a combination:

```
var tmp = $.fn.scrollspy.Constructor.prototype.process;
var delay = 5000 //ms
$.fn.scrollspy.Constructor.prototype.process = function () {
  console.log('ff wachten')
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){tmp.call(that)},delay);
  delay=5000;
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**2**

> Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data
>   attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-offset="".
>
> Name  type    default description offset  number  10  Pixels to offset from
>   top when calculating position of scroll.